# How to generate a glow effect around a button (Image) using KineticJS to create clicking sensation?

Tags: kineticjs

I created a few button with images using KineticJS. Now, I would like to generate a glow effect around a button (Image) using KineticJS to create clicking sensation. Please help me in developing this.

Comment: Please give me your button code..

Answer (score 0):

You can add a shadow to your button to create your glow effect:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/NxTW7/

[image]

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 350,
    height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

    var button=new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:30,y:30,width:50,height:35,fill:"green",stroke:"black",strokeWidth:3,
    });
    button.on("mousedown",function(){
        this.setShadowColor("green");
        this.setShadowBlur(20);
        layer.draw();
    });
    button.on("mouseup  mouseleave",function(){
        this.setShadowColor("transparent");
        this.setShadowBlur(0);
        layer.draw();
    });
    layer.add(button);
    layer.draw();

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```